# django passing context data from post method

Tags: python, django, django-views

here is my `views.py`

```
class DoctorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Doctor
    context_object_name = "doctor"
    template_name = "adminplus/pages/doctor_profile.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DoctorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = {
            "edit_form": forms.DoctorEditForm(instance=self.object),
            "password_change_form": forms.PasswordChangeForm(self.object.user),
        }
        context.update(data)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST.get("change-password"):
            form = forms.PasswordChangeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print("valid form here!")
                # ... 
            else:
                print("invalid form : ", form.errors)

        return render(request, self.template_name, ?? )
```

I've no idea how can i pass `get_context_data` back to my **template**. (or anything that works.. idk new to django:)

~Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass contex to `render` directly:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    context = self.get_contex_data(**kwargs)
    return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the return:

```
return render(request, self.template_name, context=self.context )
```